# Julia plotting: "using Winston" fails to make "FramedPlot" available

Tags: julia

I'm a new Julia user having trouble plotting. I hit the commands below, which have worked in the past, but they now result in an error. I have tried to implement solutions based on this:
http://julia-users.narkive.com/ejop940d/problem-in-using-winston

and this:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/julia-users/a1g5yT_XosQ/zGHex5SMOooJ

but the (annoying) refrain is "Works for me, what's your problem?" I'd appreciate any help you could offer.

```
using Winston
decay_plot = FramedPlot(title="Eric Tests Gillespie Implementation", xlabel="Rxn Time", ylabel="Remaining Molecules")

Error: FramedPlot not defined
```

System details: I'm using Juno on a 64-bit system, Mac OS 10.9.5. VERSION evaluates to v"0.3.7" and Pkg.installed("Winston") yields v"0.11.9". When I run `Pkg.build("Winston")`
I get this text on the console. The same errors appear when I try `Pkg.build("Cairo", "Tk")` as a follow-up.

```
>INFO: Building Cairo
>
>==================[ ERROR: Cairo ]=================
>
>@setup not defined
>
>while loading /Users/EricKernfeld/.julia/v0.3/Cairo/deps/build.jl, in expression >
>starting on line 4
>
>INFO: Building Tk
>
>================[ ERROR: Tk ]==================
>
>@setup not defined
>while loading /Users/EricKernfeld/.julia/v0.3/Tk/deps/build.jl, in expression >starting on line 5
>
>
>==================[ BUILD ERRORS ]=================
>
>WARNING: Cairo and Tk had build errors.
>
> - packages with build errors remain installed in /Users/EricKernfeld/.julia/v0.3
> - build the package(s) and all dependencies with `Pkg.build("Cairo", "Tk")`
> - build a single package by running its `deps/build.jl` script
```

Comment: Does `using Winston` complete without error?  If the module doesn't load properly then it's certainly possible that `FramedPlot` isn't exported

Comment: `using Winston` does complete without error. I'm sorry, but lacking experience, I don't know what "isn't exported" means or how to address it.

Comment: Update: Julia also doesn't recognize  `savefig`, another element of `Winston`.

Comment: What's the output of `Pkg.installed("Winston")` and `Pkg.build("Winston")`?

Comment: `Pkg.installed("Winston")` yields `v"0.11.9"` and `Pkg.build("Winston")` gives  a check-mark in Juno, but spits errors onto the console. I've modified the question to include the error text.

Comment: Update: Re-started Julia once, and it didn't work. Restarted Julia again, now it works. Growing pains?

Comment: I have experienced apparent inter-package version dependency/compatibility issues.  I wonder if this is another example.